# Calculate Trailing 30, 60, 90 data for rent change in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, calculated-columns

I am trying to calculate the rent percentage change for records that have a begin date (leasefrom) 60 days or less than the run date of the report (#todate#).

Similar to an excel formula.

=SUMIFS('Trade Out'!$J:$J,'Trade Out'!$H:$H,">="&DATE(2023,8,31)-60)/SUMIFS('Trade Out'!$L:$L,'Trade Out'!$H:$H,">="&DATE(2023,8,31)-60)-1

The Excel sheet is 'Trade Out', Column H is the date, Column J and L are the beginning and ending rent amounts.

I have calculated the column data in SQL, but the Summary does not match the Excel output.

SQL:   CASE WHEN datediff(day,t.dtleaseFrom,'#ToDate#') <=60 THEN Isnull(chg.CDESTIMATED , uh.crent)/ Isnull(chg.PRent, 0)-1 ELSE 0 END Day60,

I was hoping that SSRS could do a Summary lookup instead of having to calculate in SQL.

I have had no luck, as in my SSRS code is giving me an error: Value of Integer cannot be converted to System.timespan

=IIF((CDATE(Fields!LeaseFrm.Value) - CDATE(Parameters!ToDate.Value)) <=60,
SUM(Fields!rent.Value)/SUM(Fields!MarketPast.Value)-1,0)

Excel:

[image]

SSRS:
[image]